# Regular expression pattern to validate name field

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following requirements for validating an input field:

- It should only contain alphabetical characters and spaces.
- It cannot contain spaces at the beginning or end of the string.
- It cannot contain any other special character.

For example, the expression should accept the following string `"my name is wish"`.

The regular expression which I'm using is:

```
RegExp.Pattern = "^[\a-zA-Z]*[\s]*[\a-zA-Z]*[\s]*[\a-zA-Z]*$"
```

When I enter a name as "abc abc abc6" it accepts it as valid. It should give an error since a number is entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pattern

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

Explanation of pattern:

```
^          Start of string  
[a-zA-Z]   Any character in the class a to z or A to Z  
+          One or more repititions  
(?:   )    Match expresion but don't capture
\s+        Whitespace, One or more repititions  
*          Zero or more repititions  
$          End of string
```

Comment: thank you so much it works the great, also now this pattern finds the error when i write "abc abc abc6". Thank you so much once again.

Comment: can you please tell me whats the use of ":" colon operator in the above pattern.

Comment: in [a-zA-Z] are characters like 'è' 'ç' 'ß' etc. also included?

Comment: Let's say I am entering full name, how can I allow space between first name and last name?